# RAM Change on the raspberry pi 4

Tags: storage, memory

Can you change your RAM in your pi that you get 16gb RAM?

Comment: No. You get what you bought.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: RAM is a hardware thing. A thing that you can touch and is present physically, as shown in this picture: https://assets.raspberrypi.com/static/raspberry-pi-4-labelled-f5e5dcdf6a34223235f83261fa42d1e8.png

It is not removable even if you want to upgrade it. It is soldered directly to the board. You get the same amount of RAM that you buy.
It is not something you can change in software.

BTW: If you want to get full use of your ram with compression (shrinking stuff in ram so that more stuff can fit in) and use it as SWAP (using any storage as ram) you can get a little more performance. Check out this: https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps
Download pi-apps and try the "More RAM" app. Very nice app.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer, Maybe.
If you have, and can use, a soldering heat-gun, it has been done.
At least 1Gb to 8Gb has. 16Gb seemed as step too far.

[See](https://hackaday.com/2023/03/05/upgrade-ram-on-your-pi-4-the-fun-way/)